# How to compose column name using another column's value for withColumn in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to add a new column to a `DataFrame`. The value of this column is the value of another column whose name depends on other columns from the same `DataFrame`.

For instance, given this:

```
+---+---+----+----+
|  A|  B| A_1| B_2|
+---+---+----+----+
|  A|  1| 0.1| 0.3|
|  B|  2| 0.2| 0.4|
+---+---+----+----+
```

I'd like to obtain this:

```
+---+---+----+----+----+
|  A|  B| A_1| B_2|   C|
+---+---+----+----+----+
|  A|  1| 0.1| 0.3| 0.1|
|  B|  2| 0.2| 0.4| 0.4|
+---+---+----+----+----+
```

That is, I added column C whose value came from either column A_1 or B_2. The name of the source column A_1 comes from concatenating the value of columns A and B.

I know that I can add a new column based on another and a constant like this:

```
df.withColumn("C", $"B" + 1)
```

I also know that the name of the column can come from a variable like this:

```
val name = "A_1"
df.withColumn("C", col(name) + 1)
```

However, what I'd like to do is something like this:

```
df.withColumn("C", col(s"${col("A")}_${col("B")}"))
```

Which doesn't work.

NOTE: I'm coding in Scala 2.11 and Spark 2.2.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve your requirement by writing a `udf` function. **I am suggesting `udf`, as your requirement is to process `dataframe` *row by row* contradicting to *inbuilt functions* which functions *column by column***.

But before that you would need *array of column names*

```
val columns = df.columns
```

Then write a `udf` function as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def getValue = udf((A: String, B: String, array: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => array(columns.indexOf(A+"_"+B)))
```

where

```
A is the first column value
B is the second column value
array is the Array of all the columns values
```

Now just call the `udf` function using `withColumn` api

```
df.withColumn("C", getValue($"A", $"B", array(columns.map(col): _*))).show(false)
```

You should get your desired output `dataframe`.

Answer (score 1):

You can `select` from a `map`. Define map which translates name to column value:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, concat_ws, lit, map}

val dataMap = map(
  df.columns.diff(Seq("A", "B")).flatMap(c => lit(c) :: col(c) :: Nil): _*
)

df.select(dataMap).show(false)
```

```
+---------------------------+
|map(A_1, A_1, B_2, B_2)    |
+---------------------------+
|Map(A_1 -> 0.1, B_2 -> 0.3)|
|Map(A_1 -> 0.2, B_2 -> 0.4)|
+---------------------------+
```

and select from it with `apply`:

```
df.withColumn("C", dataMap(concat_ws("_", $"A", $"B"))).show
```

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|A_1|B_2|  C|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  1|0.1|0.3|0.1|
|  B|  2|0.2|0.4|0.4|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

You can also try mapping, but I suspect it won't perform well with very wide data:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val outputEncoder = RowEncoder(df.schema.add(StructField("C", DoubleType)))

df.map(row => {
   val a = row.getAs[String]("A")
   val b = row.getAs[String]("B")
   val key = s"${a}_${b}"
   Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq :+ row.getAs[Double](key))
})(outputEncoder).show
```

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|A_1|B_2|  C|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  1|0.1|0.3|0.1|
|  B|  2|0.2|0.4|0.4|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

and in general I wouldn't recommend this approach.

If data comes from `csv` you might consider skipping default `csv` reader and use custom logic to push column selection directly into parsing process. With pseudocode:

```
spark.read.text(...).map { line => {
  val a = ???  // parse A
  val b = ???  // parse B
  val c = ???  // find c, based on a and b
  (a, b, c)
}}
```

Comment: could you please help on this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55332897/how-to-add-new-column-to-datasetrow-using-map-function-on-the-dataset